# ElGamal - What if the Decisional Diffie-Hellmann problem could be solved?

Tags: elgamal-encryption

I have read that if the DDH problem could be efficiently solved, the IND-CPA would not hold for ElGamal.

I don't see why it makes ElGamal less secure if you have $g^a$, $g^b$ and $g^c$

Answer (score 4):

Let $\mathcal{A}(g^a,g^b,g^c)$ be a DDH adversary which will return 1 if it thinks that $c = ab$, and return 0 if it thinks that $c$ is chosen from random.

Let $a$ is a private key and $g^a$ is a public key, we can attack IND-CPA of ElGamal encryption as follows.

1. Random $m_0,m_1$ and send them to the challenger.
2. The challenger will random $b$ and send $(g^b,g^{ab} m_i)$ back, where $i$ is the experiment number.
3. We can call $\mathcal{A}(g^a,g^b,\frac{g^{ab}m_i}{m_0})$. If it returns 1, we will guess that we are in Experiment 0, but, if it returns 0, we will guess that we are in Experiment 1.

Now we can distinguish between Experiment 0 and Experiment 1 easily.